# React 18 and Net Framework Server Side Rendering

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, server-side-rendering

I am working on a project where the back end is written in C# using .Net Framework (4.8) and the front end in React 18.

Are there any option to Rendering the React (SSR) in .NET?

I have tried https://reactjs.net/ but there is no support yet for React 18.

I am thinking in calling a node server from C# to get the html from react but I was wondering if there are any better option to avoid calling a NodeJS server.